# Why Tomcat always return "text/html;"?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

Tomcat always returns http header Content-Type as `"text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"`, if I set it in my JSP page via `'response.setContentType("application/xml")'` or `<%@page contentType="application/xml" %>` still same. I use Tomcat 7.0.5, but it also occurs in Tomcat 6 and 5?

Comment: what do you set the content type to?

Comment: I use javascript pluging that check header if it's xml or not, if not it's throw an error, even the content is actually only xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've to define **some** content type, not an empty one. If it's supposed to be generic text/plain content, then do so:

```
<%@page contentType="text/plain" %>
```

You can find an overview of most common content types [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types).

Answer (score 4):

Check you're setting the content type *before* sending any output.

Comment: ...including any whitespace...